# Device mapper target to "change" sector size?

Tags: device-mapper

I'm wondering if there exists a device mapper target that I can use to make a device appear to have a different sector size.

For example, let's say I set the "virtual" sector size to 448; then, every time I try to write 512 bytes, the mapper would redirect 448 of these bytes to one sector, and 24 bytes to the following sector.

I'm aware this would cause performance issues due to misalignments, and for I know break some software.  In fact, that's why I'd like to have it, to see what it's performance impact would be.